# Testing For Two Pairs In a Given String

Tags: java, string, loops, boolean

You get user input of a string of four positive integers ex "0 1 1 2" test to see if there are two pairs present in the string.  The IntegerPairs object will have a constructor that takes no arguments and the following two methods:

`public void setPairString(String str)` - This method will take a string as an argument and then store it in an instance variable.

`public boolean hasTwoPairs()` - This will return true when there are only two pairs present in the string.

You can use a Scanner on a string as well as System.in. It works the same way but the constructor takes a string rather than System.in.

After you are done with the scanner be sure to call `{your scaner variable name}.close();`
Don't be afraid to make local variables. You can use them to hold the numbers you get from the string.

That is my project and I am horribly lost.... Don't want anyone to do it for me, of course, but I would love to have even just a little more instruction on this. My code so far: (not very much at all and I have been sitting here stumped for 3-4 hours straight)

My class:

```
public class IntegerPairs {

private String str;

public IntegerPairs(String pairs){
    str = pairs;
}
public void setPairString(String str){
    this.str = str;
}
public boolean hasTwoPairs(){
```

No idea what to do for the boolean method. I am assuming I have to do a loop somewhere?

Haven't even gotten to the main class because I need to figure this out first.

***EDIT***

This was more what I was looking for:

```
public class IntegerPairs {

    private String theString;

    public IntegerPairs() {

    }

    public void setPairString(String str) {
        theString = str;
    }

    public boolean hasTwoPairs() {
        String a = theString.substring(0, 1);
        String b = theString.substring(1, 2);
        String c = theString.substring(2, 3);
        String d = theString.substring(3, 4);

        boolean isThereTwopairs = (a.equals(b) && c.equals(d)) ? true
                : ((a + b).equals(c + d)) ? true : false;
        return isThereTwopairs;
    }
}


Then the main class:

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntegerPairs Str = new IntegerPairs();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter 4 numbers:");
        String pairIn = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.close();
        Str.setPairString(pairIn);
        boolean isThereTwoPairs = Str.hasTwoPairs();
        String whatToPrint = (isThereTwoPairs == true) ? "There Are Two Pairs"
                : "There Are Not Two Pairs";
        System.out.print(whatToPrint);

    }
}
```

Took me a while but finally got it.  My next question is: I am running a Junit test but it's telling me that:

> "Newly constructed IntegerPairs object should not have two pairs.",

`ip.hasTwoPairs());`

Not quite sure what that means because my constructor has no assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is use a `loop` and an `if statement` `to compare every character to every other` `character in the string` and `use a counter` when a pair is found but if the counter is not equal to two, your boolean should be made to return false. Your boolean method should check the counter that's all.

Comment: Two pairs as in two double numbers so ex. "1 1 2 2" or "3 3 4 4" it takes a 4 character string (with spaces) of 4 positive integers to check and see if there are two pairs within those 4 integers. So if there's 2 pairs (all 4 numbers) it would return true and if only one pair it would still be false.

Comment: So then if the counter is not equal to two the boolean method should return false. How about accepting my answer if you think it is worthy.

Answer (score 2):

Is it absolutely necessary to resolve this through constructors? It seems like ***regex*** is the perfect key.

Below is one,  **not elegant & quickly baked **, solution. Enjoy.

public class Success {

```
static int f = 4; //declare a static variable that may suffer modifications below

public static void main(String[] args) {


    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert, please, 4 digits!"); // the input may be any character
    int one= input.replaceAll("[^1]", "").length(); //using regex and the length() method, we count for how many times the digit 1 is repeated in our String: input. The result is stored in int one
    int two= input.replaceAll("[^2]", "").length(); // the same here, for digit 2
    int three= input.replaceAll("[^3]", "").length(); // the same, for digit 3
    int four= input.replaceAll("[^4]", "").length(); // the same, for digit 4
    int five= input.replaceAll("[^5]", "").length(); // the same, for digit 5
    int six= input.replaceAll("[^6]", "").length(); // the same, for digit 6
    int seven= input.replaceAll("[^7]", "").length(); // the same, for digit 7
    int eight= input.replaceAll("[^8]", "").length(); // the same, for digit 8
    int nine= input.replaceAll("[^9]", "").length(); // the same, for digit 9
    int zero= input.replaceAll("[^0]", "").length(); // the same, for digit 0

    if(one == 2){ // if the stored result in int one, from the operation above is 2, then we have a pair in the inputted String

       f = f-2; // thus, we remove 2 from f (f was declared above as static, 4). The point is if f, by the end of those if statements will be equal to 0, then our String has 2 pairs of digits
    }
    if(one == 3){ // if the stored result in int one, from the operation above is 3, then we have a pair in the inputted String

       f = f-2; // thus, we remove 2 from f
    }

    if(one == 4){ // if the stored result in int one, from the operation above is 4, then we have two pairs in the inputted String
        f=f-4;
    }
    if(two == 2){

       f = f-2;
    }

    if(two == 4){
        f=f-4;
    }
    if(two == 3){

       f = f-2;
    }
    if(three == 2){

       f = f-2;
    }

    if(three == 4){
        f=f-4;
    }
    if(three == 3){

       f = f-2;
    }
    if(four == 2){

       f = f-2;
    }

    if(four == 4){
        f=f-4;
    }
    if(four == 3){

       f = f-2;
    }
    if(five == 2){

       f = f-2;
    }

    if(five == 4){
        f=f-4;
    }
    if(five == 3){

       f = f-2;
    }
    if(six == 2){

       f = f-2;
    }

    if(six == 4){
        f=f-4;
    }
    if(six == 3){

       f = f-2;
    }
    if(seven == 2){

       f = f-2;
    }

    if(seven == 4){
        f=f-4;
    }
    if(seven == 3){

       f = f-2;
    }
    if(eight == 2){

       f = f-2;
    }

    if(eight == 4){
        f=f-4;
    }
    if(eight == 3){

       f = f-2;
    }
    if(nine == 2){

       f = f-2;
    }

    if(nine == 4){
        f=f-4;
    }
    if(nine == 3){

       f = f-2;
    }
    if(zero == 2){

       f = f-2;
    }

    if(zero == 4){
        f=f-4;
    }
    if(zero == 3){

       f = f-2;
    }

    if (f == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are TWO pairs!");
    } else if (f == 2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is only ONE pair!");

    } else if (f == 4) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are NO pairs!");

    }
```

}

Comment: I honestly don't know how to use regex yet.  I am in a beginner Java class and I don't think we have gotten to that point yet... We do have to use a constructor though. Would I be using regex in the main class or my object class??  I am taking a shot here that I will need to do something like this:     String str = "1 1 2 2";
    String delimiters = " ";

    String[] str2 = str.split(delimiters);

Comment: And that will turn it into an array of split strings?? So each number will be a separate string correct?  Sorry I am really new to all of this and am not sure how to comment with my code in the right format on this site either.

Comment: Soon I will edit my answer above and post the solution, stay tuned.

Comment: I made some last modifications to the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this would be to split your `String` by spaces and put each token into a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is the token and the value is a count.

Here's a quick & dirty example:

```
String input = "0 1 1 2";
// splitting on space
String[] split = input.split(" ");
// initializing map
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
// iterating over split
for (String s: split) {
    // token already present: incrementing its count
    if (map.containsKey(s)) {
        map.put(s, map.get(s) + 1);
    }
    // token not there yet: putting count as 1
    else {
        map.put(s, 1);
    }
}
// initializing counter for # of pairs
int pairsCounter = 0;
// iterating counts
for (Integer i: map.values()) {
    // a count == 2 is a pair: increasing count of pairs
    if (i == 2) {
        pairsCounter++;
    }
}
// printing output: do we have exactly 2 pairs?
System.out.printf("Input contains 2 numerical pairs? %b%n", pairsCounter == 2);
```

**Output**

```
Input contains 2 numerical pairs? false
```

Answer (score 1):

If your working with numbers, you should store them to int, double etc. I would recommend that you would do that in constructor, after that, you can easily check if first two numbers are pair, and do same for second two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

So the first thing is:

> IntegerPairs object will have a constructor that takes no arguments

But your constructor does take an argument.

Now to the solution. Try to implement the following algorithm:

1. Split the string by using the space ' ' as delimiter
   Hint: look [at the documentation for String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)
2. The result is an array of the split strings. You can insert a check, if there are really four elements. If you don't want to: skip this point
3. Then you can simply check, if first and second element are equal and third and fourth element are equal, since this is the only possible way of having two pairs.

Good Luck!

Comment: 1 2 1 2, also has two pairs even though the same integers are not at consecutive index positions when your replace the spaces with an empty string. Check your third instruction again.

Comment: @rert588 this is a more flexible definition of pair - I assumed that they need to be adjacent. Cannot figure it out by reading the original post again, but if they don't need to be adjacent, you could sort the array first and then apply step 3.